# RewriteRule and get 1,2 or 3 values with php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using .htaccess + php `$_GET` I want to Go to a link at first like this `Browse/link` then `Browse/link/season` and then `Browse/link/season/episode` but I got problem with `.htaccess` if I don't go to the last link its not working.

How is it possible to make .htaccess allow me to do that if I remove `&episode=$3` and go to link Browse/link/ it will work.

it will get season empty but how can I make with `&episode=$3` in it.

.htaccess Code:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^Browse/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ Browse.php?link=$1&season=$2&episode=$3
```

simple $_GET php:

```
$getlink = $_GET["link"];
$getseason = $_GET["season"];
$gerepisode = $_GET["episode"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you have no folder `Browse`, so I am leaving out the two condition checks. They only slow down things.

Then you can just use 3 rules, and `[^/]` in the regex that matches everything but a slash.

```
RewriteRule ^Browse/([^/]+)/?$ Browse.php?link=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^Browse/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ Browse.php?link=$1&season=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^Browse/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ Browse.php?link=$1&season=$2&episode=$3 [L]
```